# Is Windows Authentication (NTLM) on Windows Server 2008 R2 secure for Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, iis, authentication, encryption, ntlm

Is it generally considered secure to use Windows NTLM Authentication for Sharepoint 2010 on a Windows 2008 R2 server?

This Sharepoint install WILL BE exposed to the Internet.
Is NTLM in 2008 R2 sent as clear text, or some otherwise easily defeat-able encryption?

I want to be sure we aren't making ourselves vulnerable by this authentication method.

My gut says forms authentication with SSL would be best.

Comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gut is leading you in the right direction.  NTLMv2 can be vulnerable to an attack known as a [forwarding attack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300806.aspx) where an interloper could set up a proxy between your client and server and hijack an authenticated session.

Comment: Does that mean though, that NTLMv2 would be used at least in 2008 R2 with IIS7 and sharepoint 2010?  I wasn't clear on that part.

Comment: My understanding is that it depends on your IIS configuration as to what mechanisms you accept.  There's certainly nothing wrong with using NTLMv2 with SSL, I would just be sure to require SSL over the public internet at large.